# Execution of Multiple procedures one after another is not working

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to execute a procedure which in turn should execute four other procedures  one after the other. How do I acheive this?

```
Create or replace procedure mainproc
as
begin
tack(400);
phno_insert;
address_insert;
academics_insert;
commit;
end;
```

Error report:

> PLS-00905: Object phno_insert is invalid. PL/SQL: Statement ignored.
>   PLS-00905: Object address_insert is invalid. PL/SQL: Statement
>   ignored. PLS-00905: Object academics_insert is invalid. PL/SQL:
>   Statement ignored.

Comment: This looks absolutely correct. Are the other procedures installed and executable (permission wise)?

Comment: Every procedure is working and can be executed. But there is a dependency on Procedure tack(400); Only if tack(400) is executed ,the other three can execute

Comment: What does tack do? Does it contain a DDL query?

Comment: Yes, Tack consists of a DDL query i.e. creating a table and populating data(400 records) in it. The remaining three procedures use that table to work.

Comment: If you create a table runtime, you can not have another procedure that statically references that table; maybe you need dynamic sql

Comment: @Aleksej is right.  I think you could avoid ddl inside `track` (what's the point  anyway, if other procedures are not dynamic)? Do only the populating  in `tack` method...

Comment: The task is that I create one stored procedure which will create a table 'x' dynamically, populate records and again create tables p,q,r(using the other three procedures) which  establish referential relationship with 'x' and populate their tables. So there is DDL in every procedure. And I am using 'Execute immediate' to create and alter them.

Comment: Why do you need to create them? Can't you use a global temporary table, for example?

Comment: @Darla Why are you creating tables on-the-fly? In general, it's best to have the tables pre-created, and merely populate the data at run-time. What happens to these tables after all the processing is done? Do they hang around? Maybe you should consider global temporary tables (GTTs) or partitioned tables instead?

Comment: Yes @Boneist, I do require the tables after the processing is done. Like you've said , i will first create tables and then populate data. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in the fact that you have a procedure doing a DDL over an object that is statically referenced in another procedure; for example, if I define:

```
create table runtimeTable as select 1 as one from dual;
create or replace procedure createTable is
begin
    execute immediate 'drop table runtimeTable';
    execute immediate 'create table runtimeTable as select 1 as one from dual';
end;
create or replace procedure useTable is
    vVar number;
begin
    select one
    into vVar
    from runtimeTable;
    --
    dbms_output.put_line(vVar);
end;
create or replace procedure createAndUseTable is
begin
    createTable;
    useTable;
end;
/
```

when I try to execute `createAndUseTable` I get:

> ORA-04068: existing state of packages has been discarded ORA-04065:
>   not executed, altered or dropped stored procedure "ALEK.USETABLE"
>   ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called:
>   "ALEK.USETABLE" ORA-06512: at "ALEK.CREATEANDUSETABLE", line 4
>   ORA-06512: at line 1

If you strictly need to do a DDL runtime, you need to use dynamic SQL to reference the modified object; for example if I define the procedure `useTable` this way

```
create or replace procedure useTable is
    vVar number;
begin
    execute immediate 
    'select one    
    from runtimeTable'
    into vVar;
    --
    dbms_output.put_line(vVar);
end;
```

the call to `createAndUseTable` will work:

```
SQL> exec createAndUseTable
1
```

Comment: yes, i am using dynamic SQL for DDL. But i doubt that they are being executed in parallel.The last three procedures are dependent on first procedure, so parallel job processes may affect execution.Is that it?